# Dumping a subset of all tables based on some condition

Tags: database, postgresql, copy, pg-dump

We have a primary database, but also offer machines for deployment in field applications.

Often the people in the field will only want some specific data in the database.

For the simplest example say everything in the database can be filtered on a variable "location". Somebody wants to take only location=1 data with the field copy.

What is the preferred method of dumping all data/tables for reconstruction in an empy database based on some conditional selection in an existing database.

Ideally something like pg_dump... COPY could do this (I think), but is there a better method or some other tool out there to do this?

Comment: That question was asked in 09' I imagine there have been quite a few changes since then.

Comment: Not really any significant changes since then that I know of, kpurdon.